# Displaying information from another table in relation from another in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am making something like database manager client for bank accounts in learning purposes. I am working with DataTable objects and I want to display content stored in tables using relations between them, which (probably) can be done automatically using DataGrid.

For example, I have Banks, Owners and Accounts tables. How could I show Owner or Bank name in Accounts table representation instead of its ID in DataGrid?
[Current tables representation in DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILgxE.png)

I'm using DataTables as a DataContext for my DataGrid control.

```
dataGrid.DataContext = ((DataTable)table).DefaultView;
```

I've learned about DisplayMemberPath property in controls (comboboxes, listboxes etc), but I didn't find any information about how to use it in case of DataGrid rows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set AutoGenerateColumns property of Datagrid to False and create the columns yourself

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bank Name" Binding="{Binding BankName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bank Name" Binding="{Binding OwnerName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bank Name" Binding="{Binding Account}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

> For example, I have Banks, Owners, and Accounts tables. How could I show Owner or Bank name in Accounts table representation instead of its ID in DataGrid?

I assume you have 3 tables which are referenced by foreign keys. You should first JOIN them when retrieving them from your database, then it will be easy to create your view.

Comment: What if I want to use one single DataGrid for different DataTables?

Comment: No, you can't bind multiple Datatables to a single Datagrid at once, what you should actually do is, JOIN those different tables in a single table. You can use LINQ to do that in c#. If you could show the structure of those tables, and the sample output you are trying to achieve, maybe I could provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: I mean I need to bind tables with differrent structure, not multiple tables at once. Now I build columns programmatically. You helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)